# Prepopulate taxonomy field

Tags: 8, entities, taxonomy-terms

I'm writing a module that use Taxonomy terms for different data (cast, directors, ... of a movie). Now I prefill some default fields to a create node page using the hook_form_alter. The only prefill that doesn't work is the taxonomy terms.

The code that I tried for prefilling taxonomy term looks like:

```
$directorIndex = 0;
    foreach($movie->directors as $director)
    {
        if ($directorIndex > 0) {
            $form['field_movie_director']['widget'][$directorIndex] = $form['field_movie_director']['widget'][0];
            $form['field_movie_director']['widget'][$directorIndex]['#delta'] = $directorIndex;
            $form['field_movie_director']['widget'][$directorIndex]['#weight'] = $directorIndex;
        }

        $form['field_movie_director']['widget'][$directorIndex++]['target_id']['#default_value'] = get_vocabulary_term($director['name'], 'movie_director');
    }

function get_vocabulary_term($term_value, $vocabulary) {
  if ($terms = taxonomy_term_load_multiple_by_name($term_value, $vocabulary)) {
    $term = reset($terms);
  }
  else {
    $term = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::create([
      'name' => $term_value,
      'vid' => $vocabulary,
    ]);
    $term->save();
  }
  return $term;
}
```

The fields are created on the form and are filled in.But when saving the form the values are lost and only the first value of the taxonomy term field has been saved. How to fix this to save the form with all the fields?

Comment: Why are you incrementing `$directorIndex`?

Comment: Because I have multiple values for that field and need to show the different values on the create form

Comment: Oh, my bad. I wasn't paying enough attention. Have you verified that `$form['field_movie_director']['widget'][$directorIndex++]['value']['#default_value']` isn't empty after your code runs?

Comment: Yes I verified it. Their is a value in $form['field_movie_director']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] (for the first value).

Comment: Ok, so to clarify, you are trying to provide a default value for a taxonomy term autocomplete field?

Comment: Yes I am. i have a taxonomy term field with the names of the directors. And need to autofill the fields in my module.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51619/discussion-between-lukedekker-and-jimmyd).